# Getting related object of several AutoCompleteTextViews

Tags: android

I have a several views which extend from `AutoCompleteTextView` and a `Button` to perform some action.

How can I get the objects which are chosen in `the AutoCompleteTextView`s? I know, I can get an object with `getListSelection()`, but this works only in an `OnItemClickListener`, in my `onClick`-method it returns -1 all the time.

So I read the text of the `AutoCompleteTextView`, build a new object (in my example `Player`) and search the index in a list (`players`) which contains all possible objects. Is there a better way?

```
selectedPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
    for (ClearableAutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteView : playerViews) {
        String selectedName = autoCompleteView.getText().toString();
        int indexOfPlayer = players.indexOf(new Player(selectedName));
        if (indexOfPlayer != -1)
            selectedPlayers.add(players.get(indexOfPlayer));
    }
```

`ClearableAutoCompleteTextView` just extends `AutoCompleteTextView`, but forces the user to choose an item of the adapter-list and is clearable.